# geom_blank drops NA

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `geom_blank` I want to add some new factor levels, but I can't seem to do this *and* keep the `NA` level

```
library('ggplot2')
pl <- ggplot(data.frame(x = factor(c(1:2, NA)), y = 1), aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
pl
```

[image]

```
pl + geom_blank(data = data.frame(x = addNA(factor(c(0:3, NA))), y = 1))
```

[image]

I would like to have the x at 0,1,2,3,NA using `geom_blank`

Comment: I guess I can switch the order: `ggplot(data.frame(x = factor(c(1:2, NA)), y = 1), aes(x, y)) + geom_blank(data = data.frame(x = addNA(factor(c(0:3, NA))), y = 1)) + geom_point()` not ideal though -- then I might ask how to reorder the layers of a ggplot object that is already created (or insert a layer at some index)

Comment: where that crazy cat @baptiste at

Comment: It works if I wrap `x` in `paste()`: `pl <- ggplot(data.frame(x = paste(factor(c(1:2, NA))), y = 1), aes(x, y)) + geom_point(); pl + geom_blank(data = data.frame(x = paste(addNA(factor(c(0:3, NA)))), y = 1), aes(x, y))`.

Comment: @jav in that case `NA` are converted to strings and no longer `NA`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I hoped in the comments, a work-around could be re-ordering the layers if the plot is already made, and this should work for ggplots in general.

```
library('ggplot2')
pl <- ggplot(data.frame(x = factor(c(1:2, NA)), y = 1), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_blank(data = data.frame(x = addNA(factor(c(0:3, NA))), y = 1))


## not what I want
pl


## this is what I want
pl$layers <- rev(pl$layers)
pl
```

[image]

Comment: What happens to your points if you self-answer a bounty like this? jw

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) I will lose those points

Comment: Well, that sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, when you have multiple layers with separate datasets, factor levels can get messed overridden.  You can fix this by setting the limits on the discrete scale:

```
pl <- ggplot(data.frame(x = factor(c(1:2, NA)), y = 1), aes(x, y)) + geom_point()    
pl +
  geom_blank(data = data.frame(x = addNA(factor(c(0:3, NA))), y = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=addNA(factor(c(0:3, NA))))
```

For some reason, this messes up the expansion on the axis and the NA break is at the right edge.

[[image: Almost Working[1]]

This can be fixed by manually setting the expand parameter to your liking.

```
pl <- ggplot(data.frame(x = factor(c(1:2, NA)), y = 1), aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
pl +
  geom_blank(data = data.frame(x = addNA(factor(c(0:3, NA))), y = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=addNA(factor(c(0:3, NA))), expand=c(0.25,0.25))
```

[image: Working, but must manually specify expand]

Comment: that's messier, plus if pl contains a scale_x_discrete already, this will override that. I don't see why geom_blank should drop the NA especially if I have it there already and the default is _not_ to drop NA (ie, geom_point)

Comment: For example `ggplot(data.frame(x = factor(c(1:2, NA)), y = 1), aes(x, y)) + geom_blank(data = data.frame(x = addNA(factor(c(0:3, NA))), y = 1))` works as desired (except no points), adding the point layer between drops NA, adding after keeps them. is that not weird?

Comment: Any solution here is messy as this is a bug/limitation of ggplot2.  It does not behave consistently when merging datasets from multiple layers.  I think my way is cleaner, as setting scale properties is the intended way of setting these things manually across all layers, whereas reversing layers is obscure and something that just happens to work in this case.  But, as always w/ workarounds, your milage may vary...

Comment: More on this general issue here: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/577  tldr: hadley suggests either setting factor levels consistently on all datasets before feeding them in or specifying in the scale.

Comment: yes fixing the scales is the obvious answer, I am trying to avoid consistency across layers, that is why I took the geom_blank approach not setting the scales